# Is there an equivalent to kbhit in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I'm a beginner programmer who needs to make a simple game using JS. I've done a similar game in c++ where the character (i.e. a pixel) moves depending on the value of the input. In that project I used kbhit to get the inputs but in JS, I'm at a loss.

I tried looking around for a bit and found the scanner function but it didn't quite make sense to me and it didn't seem like the right thing to use.

Any tips?

Comment: The [`keydown` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) (and [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event)), perhaps?

Comment: JavaScript is event-based, so you define an event listener that occurs when a keyboard event occurs.